# How to input decimal numbers in C++?

Tags: c, scanf

i'm extremely beginner in terms of coding. So, i'm asking my friends to create Floyd Warshall Algorithm in C++ for my thesis. Here is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define MAX 30

void floyd(int);
int w[MAX][MAX], d[MAX][MAX][MAX];

void main()
{
int i,j,v;
clrscr();
printf("enter the no. of vertices\n");
scanf("%d",&v);
printf("enter the weights \n");

  for(i=1;i<=v;i++)
  {
   for(j=1;j<=v;j++)
    scanf("%d",&w[i][j]);
   }

 floyd(v);
 getch();
 }//end of main

 void floyd(int v)
 {
 int k, i,j;

  k=0;
for(i=1;i<=v;i++)
{
 for(j=1;j<=v;j++)
  d[k][i][j]=w[i][j];
 }

      for(k=1;k<=v;k++)
 {
       for(i=1;i<=v;i++)
{
  for(j=1;j<=v;j++)
   d[k][i][j]=min(d[k-1][i][j], d[k-1][i][k]+ d[k-1][k][j]);
  }
}

 //displayin matrix

 for(k=0;k<=v;k++)
 {
 printf(" k=%d \n",k);
   for(i=1;i<=v;i++)
   {
    printf("\n");
     for(j=1;j<=v;j++)
     printf("\t %d",d[k][i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n \n ");
  }
}
```

Since, most of my data are using decimal numbers instead of integer, the program doesn't allow me to input it. What changes should i make ? Thanks.

Comment: First thing to change -- use 0 based indices, not 1 based indices.

Comment: For starters, you'll never receive a decimal from an integer value, no matter what other integer you're trying to deduct from it. Replace your `floyd` arguments to take a `float` or `double`, and in your main define instead `float i,j,v`. Also, in your `floyd` function, use `float k,i,j`.. Your looping logic should be alright, it seems like. But I agree with @RSahu; you should use `0` as your array starting index; don't initialize with 1, it's like saying a value exists when it shouldn't.

Comment: By *decimal* numbers, I assume you meant numbers that are not integral numbers. In that case, you can use `float` or `double` as type instead of `int`. You will need to change format specifer to `%f` or `%lf`, respectively, too.

Comment: Unfortunately, "I got this code from somewhere, I don't know how it works, please help me modify it." isn't a good question. This site is for helping people learn, not doing stuff for people. You should actually learn how to code from a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/9254539) so you can do things yourself. Your friend's code contains a bunch of very bad practices by the way, including the 1-indexing, C I/O for no reason, and using macros for constants. You should also improve the indenting to make the code much easier to read.

Comment: `<conio.h>` is not a standard header. `void main` is wrong; `main` must return `int`. Don't use global variables for no reason. If you do use global variables, don't give them one-letter names.

Comment: Don't use `scanf` for user input. If you do use `scanf`, always check its return value.

Comment: Surely all you need to do is ask your friends again, and be clearer about your requirements.

Comment: Is it C or C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I won't address there correctness of your implementation of the "Floyd Warshall Algorithm", I do think I can help you read decimal values.

First, a couple of thoughts, pointers, hints. (1) your code is C and has nothing to do with C++, other than C++ originally being derived as a super-set of C many many years ago (it is now a language unto itself, but still maintains the ability to use the traditional C-library functions); (2) avoid using `<conio.h>`, it is a windows-only header, and you can use the standard library function `getchar()` to hold the terminal open until you press return instead of using `getch()`, and there is simply no need for `clrscr()`; and finally (3) avoid the use of *global variables* unless absolutely required. Declare your needed variables in `main()` and pass them as parameters to any functions that require them.

To begin, the proper declarations for `main` are `int main (void)` and `int main (int argc, char **argv)` (which you will see written with the equivalent `char *argv[]`). **note:** `main` is a function of `type int` and it returns a value. See: [C11 Standard §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup p1 (draft n1570)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p1). See also: [See What should main() return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/).

Well done, when you need a constant using `#define` is the proper way to define one (or you can use a *global* `enum` to accomplish the same thing).

What values a variable can hold is determined by the `type` you declare the variable to be. Your integer types are `char, short, int, long, long long` (along with their `unsigned` and `exact-width` counterparts) and your types for holding decimal (*floating-point*) values are `float` and `double`. (generally 32-bit and 64-bit, respectively). So in your case, if you want `w` and `d` to be able to hold decimal values, you need to declare them with the proper type, e.g.

```
#define MAX 30
...
    double w[MAX][MAX] = {{ 0.0 }},         /* double or float type */
        d[MAX][MAX][MAX] = {{{ 0.0 }}};     /* to hold decimal values */
```

(it is always a good idea to initialize arrays to all zero to avoid an inadvertent attempt to read from an element that has not yet had its value set. This is also a difference between your global declarations (initialized zero by default) and when declaring the arrays within `main()` with *automatic storage duration*)

When you are taking user input -- regardless of the function you use, you need to **validate the return** of the input function and **validate the input** itself if it is required to be within a given range, e.g.

```
    printf ("enter the no. of vertices\n");
    if (scanf ("%d", &v) != 1) {    /* always validate scanf return */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid integer input for v.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);    /* exit on failure - adjust as desired */
    }
    if (v < 0 || v > MAX) {     /* validate v within range of MAX */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: v not within 0 - %d.\n", MAX);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

To read `double` values, you simply need to change your conversion specifier from `%d` (used to read integer values) to `%lf` (used to read `double` values -- you omit the `'l'` modifier to read `float`). You must still provide the same validation, e.g.

```
    printf ("enter the weights\n");
    for (i = 0; i < v; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < v; j++)
            if (scanf ("%lf", &w[i][j]) != 1) { /* use %lf for double */
                fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid w[%d][%d].\n", i, j);
                exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
```

Declaring `w` and `d` in `main()` will require that you pass `w` and `d` as parameters to `floyd()`, e.g.

```
void floyd (double d[][MAX][MAX], double w[][MAX], int v);
```

and you call it in main as:

```
    floyd (d, w, v);
```

Putting it altogether, you could do something like the following (note: I'm on Linux and don't need `getchar()` (or `getch()` to hold the terminal open, so I have wrapped that call in preprocessor checks so that it is only called on windows):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 30

double min (double a, double b)
{
    return a < b ? a : b;
}

void floyd (double d[][MAX][MAX], double w[][MAX], int v);

int main (void) {

    int i, j, v = 0;
    double w[MAX][MAX] = {{ 0.0 }},         /* double or float type */
        d[MAX][MAX][MAX] = {{{ 0.0 }}};     /* to hold decimal values */

    // clrscr();    /* there is no need for clrscr() */

    printf ("enter the no. of vertices\n");
    if (scanf ("%d", &v) != 1) {    /* always validate scanf return */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid integer input for v.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);    /* exit on failure - adjust as desired */
    }
    if (v < 0 || v > MAX) {     /* validate v within range of MAX */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: v not within 0 - %d.\n", MAX);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf ("enter the weights\n");
    for (i = 0; i < v; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < v; j++)
            if (scanf ("%lf", &w[i][j]) != 1) { /* use %lf for double */
                fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid w[%d][%d].\n", i, j);
                exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
            }


    floyd (d, w, v);

#if defined (_WIN32) || defined (_WIN64)
    getchar();  /* only keep console open on windows - using getchar() */
#endif

    return 0;
}

/* pass d and w as parameters */
void floyd (double d[][MAX][MAX], double w[][MAX], int v)
{
    int k = 0, i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < v; i++)     /* assign values for k = 0 */
        for (j = 0; j < v; j++)
            d[k][i][j] = w[i][j];

    for (k = 1; k < v; k++)     /* index from 1 based on params for min */
        for (i = 0; i < v; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < v; j++) {   /* assign min k = 1, 2 */
            d[k][i][j] = min(d[k-1][i][j], d[k-1][i][k]+ d[k-1][k][j]);
        }

    /* display in matrix */
    for (k = 0; k < v; k++)
    {
        printf (" k = %d\n", k);
        for (i = 0; i < v; i++) {
            putchar ('\n');     /* use putchar for single characters */
            for (j = 0; j < v; j++)
                printf(" %6.2f", d[k][i][j]);
        }
        printf ("\n\n");
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
# ./bin/scanf_double_3d
enter the no. of vertices
3
enter the weights
1.1 2.2 3.3
4.4 5.5 6.6
7.7 8.8 9.9
 k = 0

   1.10   2.20   3.30
   4.40   5.50   6.60
   7.70   8.80   9.90

 k = 1

   1.10   2.20   3.30
   4.40   5.50   6.60
   7.70   8.80   9.90

 k = 2

   1.10   2.20   3.30
   4.40   5.50   6.60
   7.70   8.80   9.90
```

Look things over and let me know if this is what you intended and whether you have any further questions. Validating your algorithm is left to you.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what i need. Thank you so much

Comment: Glad I could help. Good luck with your coding.